# plot_components in python fbprophet returns duplicate plots

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am using prophet in python for time series forecasting.  After fitting the model, when I use plot_components(forecast) to plot the seasonal components, I get two copies of each plot: 2 copies of trend, daily seasonability, etc.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

put semicolon(;) after m.plot(forecast)

```
>>m.plot(forecast);
```

refer [this](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/124)